# Array like in object

Tags: javascript

I wonder if this object code is seemly correct usage to have group1 emulate an array like? I would avoid using array to avoid error.

```js
var group1={}
group1[0]={}
group1[0].fruits="Apple"
group1[0].qtystock1="1"
group1[1]={}
group1[1].fruits="Durian"
group1[1].qtystock4="2"
group1[2]={}
group1[2].fruits="Orange"
group1[2].qtystock1="3"
console.log(group1[0].qtystock4) //Should give "undefined"
```

Comment: Usage is correct, however not clear why you can't use array of objects.

Comment: An array of objects would suit this better

Comment: That code is valid, and the last line will log undefined as indicated. But what is the error you are trying to avoid? I'd use an array of objects...

Comment: I'm baffled on my other code which console.log(group1[0].y) is shown as 111 when the actual string for y is  y: "111,222" using console.log(group1) I can't understand if it's chrome dev tool bug or a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct, yes. Whether it's the *right* thing to do depends entirely on what else you're going to do with `group1`. If, for instance, you wanted to use the `length` property arrays have, then you wouldn't want to do that, because it won't have a `length`.

In general, if you're going to use something like an array, use an array; if you're going to use it as a non-array object, use an object. But in JavaScript, standard arrays are just objects with a bit of special behavior ([details on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)), so you can use an object like that if you want.

FWIW, here's the array version of that:

```
var group1 = [
    {fruits: "Apple", qtystock1: "1"},
    {fruits: "Durian", qtystock4: "2"},
    {fruits: "Orange", qtystock1: "3"}
];
console.log(group1[0].qtystock4); //Should give "undefined"
```

And a more concise version of the object you already have:

```
var group1 = {
    0: {fruits: "Apple", qtystock1: "1"},
    1: {fruits: "Durian", qtystock4: "2"},
    2: {fruits: "Orange", qtystock1: "3"}
};
console.log(group1[0].qtystock4); //Should give "undefined"
```

For the data as quoted, I'd probably use an array. I'd also probably use a consistent property name for `qtystock1`/`qtystock4`, but maybe it makes sense when you have the greater context.

Comment: In your 2nd code block, weren't there some versions of Javascript that required a key that didn't start with a number if it wasn't in quotes?  I see it works in the current Chrome, but I thought there was a reason to enclose the numeric property in quotes at some point?

Comment: @jfriend00: No, at least since the 3rd edition spec (1999; I'm not sure object initializers existed before then), the name in a property initializer has always been allowed to be *Identifier*, *StringLiteral* (either single- or double-quotes), or *NumericLiteral*.

Answer (score 1):

This is legal Javascript and I see no errors in your code.  If you assign an object a numeric property like this, the number is converted to a string (all property names in Javascript are strings) and you will end up with properties such as:

```
group1["0"]
```

which is interpreted by Javsacript the same as:

```
group1[0]
```

For code clarity, **it probably makes more sense for you to use an array** because then it will automatically maintain a `.length` property for you and you can use array functions on it like `.forEach()` and other iterators.  You can still have properties like your `.fruits` on an array object as it is an object too.

So, an array is everything an object is plus it adds the array functionality.  So, if you're using a zero-based sequence of items, you would usually gain clarity and functionality by using an array instead of a plain object and lose nothing.

As for your line of code:

```
console.log(group1[0].qtystock4)
```

that will show `undefined` because `group1[0]` is an object which does not have a `.qtystock4` property so JS will return `undefined` if you read it.